# Не удается отправить файл на email в андроид

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent

Приветствую спецов! Я начинающий в программировании на java андроид. Пытаюсь отправить файл через почтовый клиент. Файл прикрепляется к письму и появляется в почтовом клиенте. Письмо приходит на указанный адрес, но без файла. Файл не пустой, проверял файловым менеджером. Использую такой код:

```
   final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

   emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
  // Кому
  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
        new String[] { "ххххххх@gmail.com" });
  // Зачем
  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
        tema);
  // С чем
  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(new File("Logf.txt")));
```

Файл создавался во внутренней памяти таким кодом:

```
BufferedWriter Writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("Logf.txt", MODE_PRIVATE | MODE_APPEND), "UTF-8"));

Writer.write(log_text+"\n");
Writer.flush();
Writer.close();
```

заметил, что при попытке чтения файла также возникала неудача, хотя файл был непустой. Код для чтения такой:

```
  BufferedReader Reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("Logf.txt"), "UTF-8"));
  while (Reader.readLine() != null) {
        str=str+Reader.readLine()+"\n";
      }
```

В результате чтения `str` было "`null`".

Прошу спецы подскажите, что я делал не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После многих усилий наконец получилось. Для тех кому интересно:
В манифесте:

```
<applicaton>
     ....
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.your.package.name.fileprovider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

Добавил в layouts папку xml и в этой папке filepaths.xml:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="myFolder" path="logs/"/>
</paths>
```

в коде:

```
File sharedir = new File(getFilesDir(),"logs"); 
        if (!sharedir.exists()) sharedir.mkdir();
        shareName = new String("Logf.txt");
        shareFile = new File(sharedir, shareName);
        try//блок очистки лог-файла
         {
            FileOutputStream flogs = new FileOutputStream(shareFile);
            flogs.write(("Logs: "+"\n").getBytes());
            flogs.flush();
            flogs.close();
} catch(FileNotFoundException e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
       emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
      // Кому
      emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
            new String[] { "xxxxxxx@gmail.com" });
      // Зачем
      emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            tema);
      // О чём
      emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enter your message here: ");
      // С чем
      emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
      contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.your.package.name.fileprovider", shareFile);
      uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
      uris.add(contentUri);
      emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
      // Поехали!
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Send mail..."));
```

При запуске появляется почтовый клиент и в нем ваш файл. Файл успешно доходит до адресата. Благодарю woesss за поддержку.

Comment: опечатка: папка создается не в layouts. надо так: res/xml/filepaths.xml

Comment: пометьте как решение

Comment: Если в лист uris добавить не один, а хотя бы два файла, то к письму они не прикрепляются, ни один. Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Answer (score 0):

Видимо у Вас текст в файле в одну строку и Вы её пропускаете:
`while (Reader.readLine() != null)` - здесь строка уже прочитана, но Вы её не сохраняете в переменную и она теряется.
Нужно так:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("Logf.txt"), "UTF-8"));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        str += line + "\n";
    }
```

Comment: А с e-mail что?

Comment: А..., проблема не в этом!?)))... E-Mail клиент не имеет доступа к приватным файлам вашего приложения - нужно выдать разрешение. Не уверен что для этого случая подойдёт `emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)`, но попробуйте. Ну а по православно-Андроидному надо отдавать файлы через провайдер, как в примере здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43149880

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Попробую завтра и отпишусь, что получилось!

Comment: сделал всё по православно-андроидному, но, увы, пишет: Source not founde. The JAR of this belongs to container "Android Private Libraries" which does not allow modifications to source attachments on its entries

Comment: Если Вы не используете support-библиотеки, то надо добавить `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'` в build.gradle dependencies. Класс `FileProvider` взят оттуда.

Comment: спасибо большое! сейчас попробую. Что-то такое читал на форумах, но не понял как это сделать, но благодаря вам становится понятно

Comment: Что-то я замучился совсем. Я не думал, что просто послать файл из приложения на андроид окажется так сложно. В своём Eclipse установил gradle, создал в корневом каталоге файл build.gradle вставил в него инструкцию dependencies {compile 
 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'} внес библиотеку v4 в саппорты, но при обновлении gradle он сообщает, что не понимает, что я пишу в этой строке. Пытался сделать как в документации: добавлял allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
} но это не помогло

Comment: Завязывайте с эклипс - она давно не поддерживается AOSP. Я бы тоже писал в ней, но увы.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Придётся обновлять железо, а то мой старенький ноут с CoreDuo и 2 ГБ ОЗУ АСтудию не потянет

Comment: Если не изменяет память в эклипс можно было кликнуть правой по проекту -> Android Tools -> add support library.