# Проблема к отправке в письме двух файлов и более

Tags: java, android

Подобный вопрос разбирался здесь:
[Не удается отправить файл на email в андроид](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708151)

Решение, которое там есть использует:

```
new ArrayList<Uri>();
uris.add(contentUri);
emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
```

в котором передается список uri.

У меня есть uri_0 и uri_1.
добавляю в лист:

```
uris.add(uri_0);
uris.add(uri_1);
```

Этим способом мне не удалось прикрепить файлы.

Получается только вот так:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri_0);
```

Каждый по отдельности, тоже получается, но мне надо два и более файлов в одно письмо запихнуть.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4):

Все оказалось просто. 
Надо было вместо

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

записать

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
```